# To Run Multiple Input Files in One Go :

Tags: unix, awk

I am running a bash script to find range from Master.txt into File22_Jun14.txt

sh FindRange.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
gawk 'BEGIN { 
        FS="," # Field separator
        c=1    # counter
        while ((getline line < ARGV[1]) > 0) { 
            if (line !~ "Start,End,Qty,Date") { # No need for header
                F[c]=line;                   # store line
                split(line,a,",")            # split line
                F2[c]=a[1] ; F3[c]=a[2]        # store the lines range parts
                c++
            }
        }
      } 
FILENAME==ARGV[2] { 
    # Work on second file
    for (i in F) { # For every line scan the first file 
        # if within a range, step out
        if ($1>=F2[i] && $1<=F3[i]) {found=i ; break} 
        # else check next
        else {found=0}
    }  
    # if the above found anything print the line from second file
    # with the relavant line from the first
    if (found>0) { 
        print $0 "," F[found] 
    } 
    # otherwise the not found message
    else { 
        print $0 ",NotFound,NotFound,NotFound,NotFound" 
    } 
}' Master.txt    File22_Jun14_0000.txt   >Op_File33_Jun14.txt
```

Having multiple Input files like below (File22_Jun14_.txt),  i am changing the input files name manually one by one and running the above script , 
Is there any option o run all the File22_Jun14_*.txt  in one go

```
File22_Jun14_0000.txt
File22_Jun14_0001.txt
File22_Jun14_0002.txt
File22_Jun14_0003.txt
File22_Jun14_0004.txt
File22_Jun14_0005.txt
File22_Jun14_0006.txt
File22_Jun14_0007.txt
File22_Jun14_0008.txt
File22_Jun14_0009.txt
File22_Jun14_0010.txt
```

Have tried like,  `sh FindRange.sh Master.txt File22_Jun14_*.txt >Op_File33_Jun14.txt` and it is not working the way expected , any suggestions ...

**Edit:** Checking first field from File22_Jun14_0000.txt lying within in a range of Master.txt - Start and End Range if yes then need to populate all the lines from 
File22_Jun14_0000.txt and corresponding range from Master.txt else NotFound

Master.txt

```
StartRange,EndRange,Qty,Date
11,110,100,26.05.14
6001,10000,4000,03.05.14
501,805,305,03.05.14
```

File22_Jun14_0000.txt

```
11,abc,22-JUN-12.08:06:03,22-JUN-12.08:06:03,19-Apr-16,1,INR,RO0412,RC03,L7,,31
12,abc,22-JUN-12.08:06:03,22-JUN-12.08:06:03,19-Apr-16,1,INR,RO0412,RC03,L7,,31
905,abc,22-JUN-12.08:06:03,22-JUN-12.08:06:03,19-Apr-16,1,INR,RO0412,RC03,L7,,31
906,abc,30-JUN-12.01:06:49,30-JUN-12.01:06:49,19-Apr-16,1,INR,RO0412,RC03,L7,,29
28,abc,30-JUN-12.01:06:49,30-JUN-12.01:06:49,19-Apr-16,1,INR,RO0412,RC03,L7,,29
100001,def,29-MAY-13.12:05:11,29-MAY-13.12:05:11,15-Feb-17,1350,INR,RO0213,CD,K1,,30
100002,def,29-MAY-13.12:05:11,29-MAY-13.12:05:11,15-Feb-17,1350,INR,RO0213,CD,K1,,30
```

Desired Output:

```
11,abc,22-JUN-12.08:06:03,22-JUN-12.08:06:03,19-Apr-16,1,INR,RO0412,RC03,L7,,31,11,110,100,26.05.14
12,abc,22-JUN-12.08:06:03,22-JUN-12.08:06:03,19-Apr-16,1,INR,RO0412,RC03,L7,,31,11,110,100,26.05.14
905,abc,22-JUN-12.08:06:03,22-JUN-12.08:06:03,19-Apr-16,1,INR,RO0412,RC03,L7,,31,NotFound,NotFound,NotFound,NotFound
906,abc,30-JUN-12.01:06:49,30-JUN-12.01:06:49,19-Apr-16,1,INR,RO0412,RC03,L7,,29,NotFound,NotFound,NotFound,NotFound
28,abc,30-JUN-12.01:06:49,30-JUN-12.01:06:49,19-Apr-16,1,INR,RO0412,RC03,L7,,29,11,110,100,26.05.14
506,def,29-MAY-13.12:05:11,29-MAY-13.12:05:11,15-Feb-17,1350,INR,RO0213,CD,K1,,30,501,805,305,03.05.14
100002,def,29-MAY-13.12:05:11,29-MAY-13.12:05:11,15-Feb-17,1350,INR,RO0213,CD,K1,,30,NotFound,NotFound,NotFound,NotFound
```

Comment: Your script is hard-coded to work only on ARGV[2] so providing a list of file names in ARGV[3] etc. doesn't help. You don't need a BEGIN with getlines, just let awk do it's job on the first file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best I can tell your script should just be:

```
awk '
BEGIN{ FS="," }
NR==FNR { F[NR]=$0; F2[NR]=$1; F3[NR]=$2; next }
{
    do whatever you do today inside that FILENAME block
}
' Master.txt File22_Jun14_*.txt > Op_File33_Jun14.txt
```

but we can't test a solution since you didn't provide any sample input and expected output.

Comment: Ed Morton : Thanks for the inputs , have Edited and shared sample inputs and outputs , please advise

Comment: My advice - test the posted solution and let us know if it works or if you need more help.

Comment: Thanks Ed Morton , It working fine the way expected, having around 2500 input files , how to close file File22_Jun14_0000.txt once it is read and executed to avoid many files Open stage ...

Comment: Set `prev = FILENAME` in the block you already have and then add a `FNR==1{close(prev)}` block before it. If youre using GNU awk you do not need to worry about too many files open as gawk handles it for you